# Apache Camel file component with dynamic path

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to set dynamic path in camel file component to avoid platform specific paths. But camel is not allowing this as it doesn't expect $ in directory path.

What I am trying to do is to set a VM param say file.home and then use this into my file component like

> file:\${file.home}\type1

This will allow me to eliminate the platform specific path directly.
I tried externalizing this into property file but then Spring doesn't understand the camel specific dynamic language for e.g. ${in.header.abc}

Can someone help me out in achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

Those answers are not correct. If you use a BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and a PropertiesComponent, you can use dynamic values everywhere.

```
<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <value>
...normal property syntax name=value - use this in test definitions
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or use something like this in real application

```
<bean id="dummyPropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/dummy.properties" />
</bean>
```

e.g.

```
    <route id="DummyRoute">
        <from uri="file:{{dummy.int.dir}}?delay={{poll.delay}}&amp;initialDelay={{initial.delay}}&amp;{{readlockChanged}}&amp;move={{root}}/{{dummy.arch.dir}}/{{archive.dir}}&amp;moveFailed={{error.dir}}&amp;scheduledExecutorService=#scheduledExecutorService" />
            <to uri="file:{{root}}/{{dummy.int.destination.dir}}" />
    </route>
```

There is a trick with later versions of Camel: use `$simple{file.path}` instead of `${file.path}` so Spring won't strip your `${}` and pass the bare file.path to Camel. E.g. a move on an input 'from' uri might be like this:

```
move=archive/$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}/$simple{file:name}
```

http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: The use of `simple` helps with Spring property files too. Also, need to use `toD(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic uri but only in `to` endpoints (using specific components). You can't use it as `from`.

There you can find explanation how to use `toD` (from Camel 2.16) or `recipientList`: [How to use dynamic URI in to](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html)

But as I said - there is only possibility to use it in `to`. It's not possible to use it in `from`. As a workaround, you have to write a route for each location you are expecting to be in use. You can also use `autoCreate=false` option to not creating other directories automatically, because for example Linux path without `autoCreate=false` option: `/home/user/test` will create directory structure in Windows `c:\home\user\test`

Answer (score 1):

Since Camel 2.16

We can use

```
.from("file://folder")
.toD("file://folder/${file:onlyname}")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Camel File Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html):

> Camel supports only endpoints configured with a starting directory. So
>   the directoryName must be a directory. If you want to consume a single
>   file only, you can use the fileName option e.g., by setting
>   fileName=thefilename. Also, the starting directory must not contain
>   dynamic expressions with ${} placeholders. Again **use the fileName
>   option to specify the dynamic part of the filename**.

So, you could do somethings like:

```
from(...).to("file://?fileName=${somePathAndSomeFile}").to(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details about using properties within camel and/or spring xml: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments/answers in this thread are misleading, as it's possible to set the value of "from" endpoint URI to have a value of a directory taken from a properties file as asked.

Place propertyPlaceholder element under camelContext, and ensure that the properties file could be found in the classpath

```
<propertyPlaceholder location="dir.properties" />
<from id="_fromInputFolder" uri="file:{{fromDir}}?"/>
```